# How to encrypt a variable with the cryptography module?

Tags: python, encryption, module, cryptography

I'm not sure if any of you are familiar with the cryptography module, but I'm trying to encrypt a variable that stands for a string.

For example:

```
string = input('String here')
```

The example they give on the module page is:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(b"A really secret message. Not for prying eyes.")
plain_text = cipher_suite.decrypt(cipher_text)
```

Which is all fine and dandy, but when I try and replace the "Really secret message string with a variable, It doesn't work.

If it's in quotes, it just prints the name of the variable(duh)

If it's out of quotes like this: cipher_text = `cipher_suite.encrypt(bstring)`, it says variable is not defined(also duh)

But if I just put the variable in, it gives me an error: `TypeError: data must be bytes.`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html),

> bytes and bytearray objects are sequences of integers (between 0 and 255), representing the ASCII value of single bytes

I think the input needs to be like so

```
a = b"abc"
```

(Note the "b").

An alternate way of achieving this is

```
a = bytes("abc")
```

Comment: How would you format it though? Do you mean something like this?: string = input('b' + 'String_input')

Comment: I don't work with these myself, but the doc (cf above) says:

_Bytes objects can be constructed the constructor, bytes(), and from literals; use a b prefix with normal string syntax: b'xyzzy'._

Comment: I don't want to put a line of text in for encrytion like this: b'text_not_a_variable'. What I want to do is encrypt a variable like this: b'This_IS_a_variable' (see problems with the syntax I've tried above)

Comment: So if you do:  `variable=bytes(variable)` or `variable=b"variable"`
that does not work?

Comment: Not sure why but `b` was not working for me but `bytes` did.

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to `.encode()` the pass-string.

```
'my_pass'.encode() # this encodes your string to byte literal
```

More fully, it will be something like this:

```
cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt('my_pass'.encode())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bytes function
Es:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
string = input("string here")
string = bytes(string ,'utf-8')
print(string)
cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(string)
print(cipher_text) 
plain_text = cipher_suite.decrypt(cipher_text)
plain_text = plain_text.decode()
print(plain_text)
```

Output:

b"value of String"

G6373Hsh528gs(random characters)

Value of string